# Tasks List Gantt Chart showing wrong Due Date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, project-site

I am working in SharePoint Server 2013 on-premise project and have created a site collection using project template. I am using Tasks Lists where in Allitems view is showing the correct Due Date. However, Gantt chart view is showing a day less than actual due date.

For E.g. - If Due Date is December 15, in Gantt chart it is shown as Dec 14.

[image]

I have read that it's a kind of bug (may be by design) OR it has been fixed in some cumulative update for SharePoint 2013.

Would appreciate if someone knows specific answer to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to the Due Date Column to include time component as well (i.e. set  Date and Time Format: to date and time) by going to the list settings and clicking on the column name. Then you will be able to set Due Date for your tasks along with the time component. This should correct your Gantt chart as I had the same issue and this is how I resolved it.